# Simplifying a Racket function

Tags: lisp, racket

I have the following function "change" which takes a certain amount of money to be paid, the size of the bill/coin used to pay, and returns a list with the number of *"coins"* ($50, $20 $10 $5 $2 and $1) one would receive after completing the transaction:

```
(define (change total payment)
  (let [(x (- payment total))]
    (change-aux x '(50 20 10 5 2 1))))

(define (change-aux change coins)
  (cond
    [(empty? coins) empty]
    [else (let [(num-coins (floor (/ change (car coins))))]
            (append (list num-coins)
                    (change-aux (- change (* (car coins) num-coins)) (cdr coins))))]))
```

So, if I input these parameters:

```
> (change 44 200)
```

It returns the output:

```
'(3 0 0 1 0 1)
```

That's 200-44 = 156, which corresponds to 3 coins worth $50, 1 worth $5 and 1 worth $1.

My question would be if there's a more elegant, simplified way to write a similar procedure without relying on auxiliary functions, and rather use lambda, filter, map, foldr, foldl etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is for specific, objective questions about programming. Requests for general critique or review are considered to be off-topic, and should be directed to [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Thanks Brian, will keep it in mind from now on. Is there a way to manually move this question over to CodeReview? (complete newbie here)

Comment: See [How to move a question to another site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318460/how-to-move-a-question-to-another-site).

Comment: The function's interface doesn't conform to the description. The function is to take "an amount of money to be paid" (single input).  The code introduces two parameters, which the function immediately subtracts from each other and never uses again.

Comment: Note this problem is very similar to base conversion. For instance, to express 1234 in decimal is the same problem as breaking into change using the "coins" (1000 100 10 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in a different [Lisp dialect](https://www.nongnu.org) which shows how to do it with a left fold (reduce) without any mutation of an accumulator variable, as a kind of functional counterpoint to the existing solution.

```
(defun change (amount coins)
  (reduce-left (tb ((counts . rem) next-coin)
                 (let* ((coin-count (floor rem next-coin))
                        (coin-value (* coin-count next-coin)))
                   (cons (cons coin-count counts)
                         (- rem coin-value))))
               coins
               (cons '() amount)))


3> (change 156 '(50 20 10 5 2 1))
((1 0 1 0 0 3) . 0)

4> (change 88 '(50 20 10 5 2 1))
((1 1 1 1 1 1) . 0)
```

Note that the values end up reported in reverse order and wrapped in an extra `cons` cell; a "porcelain" function could be used around this "plumbing" to report the result in the expected form.

The idea is that we have an accumulator which looks like this: `(counts . remainder)`. The `counts` part of the accumulator stored in the `car` is the list of coins accumulated so far. When the reduce is done, this holds the final list. The `cdr` field holds the remaining amount to be processed; since the last coin is 1, this will always emerge as zero.

Using this accumulator structure, we process the list of coins.

On each call to our reduce kernel function, the left argument is the accumulator, and the right argument, `next-coin`, is the next coin denomination value.

I used a macro called `tb` ("tree bind") macro, which is a kind of `lambda` that provides built-in destructuring, to make it look like we have three parameters.

The initial value for the reduce job is the starting accumulator, which has an empty list of coins, and the full original amount: `(cons nil amount)` (which I rewrote to `(cons '() amount)` for better Scheme compatibility).

The reduce function is very simple: greedily calculate how many of the next coin value are needed to represent the remainder, and then calculate the new remainder, packaging these up into a new accumulator `cons` cell that is returned, and is passed to the next invocation of the function, or returned when the list of coin values has been processed.

Hopefully this points the way to *"a more elegant, simplified way to write a similar procedure without relying on auxiliary functions, and rather use lambda, filter, map, foldr, foldl etc"* that you can work out in Racket. Good luck!

Comment: This is a really clever solution as well. Thank you for sharing it! This is going to help me understand how to simplify my code in upcoming tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can.

## Final solution

```
(define (change total payment (coins '(50 20 10 5 2 1)))
  (let ((rest-diff (- payment total)))
    (map (lambda (coin)
           (let ((num-coins (floor (/ rest-diff coin))))
             (set! rest-diff (- rest-diff (* num-coins coin)))
             num-coins))
         coins)))
```

## Step by step

First of all, using inner `define`, you can get rid of the auxiliary function from the global namespace.

```
(define (change total payment)
  (define (change-aux change coins)
    (cond
      [(empty? coins) empty]
      [else (let [(num-coins (floor (/ change (car coins))))]
              (append (list num-coins)
                      (change-aux (- change (* (car coins) num-coins)) (cdr coins))))]))
  (let [(x (- payment total))]
    (change-aux x '(50 20 10 5 2 1))))
```

Then, you can pull some variables of the helper function's to the global function's lambda list.

```
(define (change total payment (coins '(50 20 10 5 2 1)))
  (define (change-aux change) ;; eliminate coins in the inner lambda list
    (cond
      [(empty? coins) empty] ;; coins in function body looked up from outer arguments
      [else (let [(num-coins (floor (/ change (car coins))))]
              (append (list num-coins)
                      (change-aux (- change (* (car coins) num-coins)) (cdr coins))))]))
  (let [(x (- payment total))]
    (change-aux x))) ;; eliminate coins in the call
```

Then, looking at the code of `change-aux`, one understands this is actually 
a looping through and trying to fit maximal multiples of current value 
into the rest of the difference remaining - and collecting those reults. One could loop using `map` and use `set!` to mutate the rest.

```
(define (change total payment (coins '(50 20 10 5 2 1)))
  (let ((rest-diff (- payment total)))
    (map (lambda (coin)
           (let ((num-coins (floor (/ rest-diff coin))))
             (set! rest-diff (- rest-diff (* num-coins coin)))
             num-coins))
         coins)))
```

Then, you call like above:

```
(change 44 200)
;; '(3 0 0 1 0 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining your solution so clearly! That's really going to help me understand lambdas/mapping better.